# How to create a Activiti Multiinstance Task programmatically?

Tags: java, bpmn, activiti

i try to create a multiinstance workflow programmatically.

I got these BPMN xml that works fine:

```
<userTask id="multiTask" name="Review task ${loopCounter}" activiti:assignee="${reviewer}">
  <multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics isSequential="false" activiti:collection="reviewersList" activiti:elementVariable="reviewer">
    <completionCondition>${nrOfCompletedInstances > maxReviewer }</completionCondition>        
  </multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics>
</userTask>
```

How i can do these with pure Java?
I started with these:

```
MultiInstanceLoopCharacteristics loopChar = new MultiInstanceLoopCharacteristics();
```

but i dont know how to go on.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want this to deploy a business process programmatically. I guess the way to link a `org.activiti.bpmn.model.MultiInstanceLoopCharacteristics` to a `org.activiti.bpmn.model.Task` is like this :

```
MultiInstanceLoopCharacteristics loop = new MultiInstanceLoopCharacteristics();
UserTask task = new UserTask();
task.setLoopCharacteristics(loop);
```

well then you should deploy your process programmatically (because you are using bpmn model objects not the actual runtime (engine ones))